# libraries - how to?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Hello guys sorry i'm still new with android studio and java so i got a problem with my code as you can see in these screenshots, I wrote those lines to fix the error:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

and yes the error was solved but when i tried to generate a signed apk with release mode it tells me that it's impossible but before fixing the problem with the lines up i can generate an apk easily [screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfgHB.png)

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Pa8t.png)

help me please if you know to solution of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update all those lines that are yellow first (hover over them and accept the recommended version number). Those are all outdated dependencies. Then hover over the line showing the error and keep adding the specific implementations that it recommends (where it says "Examples include..."). You're on the right track with the ones you added already, but it'll take you all day if you don't update the yellow lines first.

Comment: thanks the error is gone also the yellow line are normal now as i did update them but still can't generate an apk

Comment: What's the error that appears in the Build window when trying to generate the APK? Update your original post to show us.

Comment: okay but i'm still new with this site i don't know how to update but i'll find a way to

Comment: i clean the project and the apk file now can be generated but when i install the apk on my android phone ones i tried to launch the app it crash and close with a message (Unfortunately, "app-name" has stopped)

Comment: We'll need the stack trace that shows up in the Log window when the crash occurs.

Comment: That's not the stack trace. You should open the Logcat window, cause the crash to occur, and find the red text indicating what the Exception is that caused the crash. What you included in your post is from the Build window.

Comment: Thank you bro i solved the problem now everything is working good thanks to your help

Answer (score 1):

add this two lines to your build.gradle file

```
dependencies {

   implementation com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0
   implementation com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to update the given libraries in order to do so, like :

> First, you can do it by pointing the mouse (hover) in the given libraries with the yellow mark, and then by pressing ALT + ENTER.
>
> Secondly by going through the documentation and checking one by one [click here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup#choosing).

Ps : after that sync your gradle, and it's all ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have to update

> com.facebook.fresco....

and

> com.google.android....

dependencies. Old version of these dependencies may have old version of support library. This may lead a conflict so updating these dependencies to latest version could solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the third party libraries may sometimes use different versions of support libraries, you can fix by specifying fixed version like this

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '28.0.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```